# Emacs Org-Mode: Turn off linum

Tags: emacs, org-mode, emacs23

I've recently moved from `vim` to `Emacs` because I want to use `org-mode`. I opened a ~10000 line, 50kb file in `Emacs23` `Org-mode` and proceeded to add about 10 first-level headings. Performance on a quad-core with 3GB RAM in Emacs23 under Ubuntu 10.04/32bit was so slow that it was unusable. I found [two](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/28097/focus=29447) [threads](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/37860/focus=37864) on the `Org-mode` email list discussing this. It seems that enabling `linum` causes the slow performance. I can live without line numbers in `.org` files if I have to, but I don't want to disable line numbers for all files I edit. If I'm going to "live" in `Emacs', I'll want line numbers for all other files.

How can I disable `linum` for some or all `.org` files only? Is it possible to do this if I have several files open in `Emacs` and switch between them?  I found some discussion about disabling line numbers for major modes [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers#toc8), but there was nothing that I could implement (although the `linum-off.el` script [mentioned](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/linum-off.el) on the page looks promising, I don't (yet) know (E)Lisp, so I can't change it as I would need).

I updated `Org-mode` from version 6.21b which came with `Emacs23` to version 7.5, but it made no difference. Performance in `Emacs` GUI is so bad that the application fails to respond at all. Performance with `-nw` is "better", but still unusable.

Comment: +1. +1. +1. (Apparently the SO has a bug where +1 works only the first time). I cannot stress enough how much has this helped me.

Comment: linum slows down pasting into *any* mode. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`linum-off.el` mentioned in my quesiton has solved this. Instructions are in the file: place the file into the Emacs load-path and add `(require 'linum-off)` to ~/.emacs. This script turns off line numbering for the modes specified only. I've tested it and it works fine.

Comment: Simpler to use (global-linum-mode) and (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (linenum-mode 0))) in your ~/.emacs.el.

Comment: @bzg: Thanks for your comment, which addresses my question directly. However, "linum-off.el" allows line numbers to be disabled in several modes, which is useful [`(defcustom linum-disabled-modes-list '(eshell-mode wl-summary-mode compilation-mode org-mode dired-mode)`].

Answer (score 9):

Try adding this to your .emacs:

```
(defun nolinum ()
  (global-linum-mode 0)
)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'nolinum)
```

This is assuming that you use linum and not something else to number lines. Anyway, you can add this hook to org-mode to disable anything that might make org slow *only* when you're using org-mode.

Disclaimer: I don't have linum installed so I can't test this, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I added the lines to .emacs and opened a .org file (which automatically puts Emacs into org-mode), but line numbers are still present. The same is true if I open some other file and then visit a .org file -- the line numbers are still present. I might try the `linum-off.el` script mentioned in my question.

Comment: I changed your script to read "nil" instead of "0" and when opening a .org file, Emacs reports "Toggling global-linum-mode off; better pass an explicit argument.", but line numbers remain. This text is not shown when the line contains "0" instead of "nil" (as I said, I don't know Elisp).

Comment: Solved. See "Update" in question.

Comment: Global minor modes tend not to cooperate with the usual way of doing things with mode hooks -- the standard macros for defining global minor modes use `after-change-major-mode-hook` to turn the mode on, and that hook runs after the mode hook. So your mode hook briefly switches the mode off, and then it gets switched back on again.

Answer (score 8):

If you type M-x customize, go to Linum in the Convenience group, change Linum Eager to off, or change Linum Delay to on, it will improve performance greatly.

On my laptop (3 GB RAM, dual core) the performance drawback (of this versus having linum off) is unnoticeable, however on my netbook there may still be some slight performance issues with a ~3000 line 130KB file (~50-150 ms delay when paging).

Comment: Actually, reading the code of linum, it's one or the other, not both. ` (if linum-eager
            (add-hook 'post-command-hook (if linum-delay
                                             'linum-schedule
                                           'linum-update-current) nil t)`

Answer (score 5):

Use [nlinum](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nlinum.html), a much faster alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to add (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode 0))).

Comment: Have you tested this? In my case (with `global-linum-mode` on) it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following which worked out pretty well:

```
(defun nolinum ()
  (interactive)
  (message "Deactivated linum mode")
  (global-linum-mode 0)
  (linum-mode 0)
)

(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'nolinum)

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'nolinum)
```

Of course, you do not need the keybinding. I suggest you leave it in for testing purposes and disable it if everything works fine.